# Senders objectName is absent | QT & Cpp

Tags: c++, qt

I have created a little UI with a simple toolbar. I am initing the toolbar within the `initToolbar`function. This function is within a Class inheriting from `QMainWindow`.

```
void Main_Frame::initToolBar() {
    rectangle.setText(rectangle_text);
    circle.setText(circle_text);
    triangle.setText(triangle_text);
    triangle.setObjectName(triangle_id);
    circle.setObjectName(circle_id);
    rectangle.setObjectName(rectangle_id);
    toolBar.addAction(&triangle);
    toolBar.addAction(&circle);
    toolBar.addAction(&rectangle);
    connect(

&toolBar, &QToolBar::actionTriggered, this, [=]() {
        process_toolbar_ac_evt(*sender());
    });
}
```

I want any tool bar events to be processed through `process_toolbar_ac_ect(QObject obj)`. Within that method, I want to decide what action (within the toolbar) has been triggered.I want to do this by the `object`name. Therefore I have given any action an object name. But when I call `sender().objectName()` I get an empty `QString`.

My suggestion is, that sender returns a pointer to on of my actions that I put to the toolbar. If this is the case, why I get an empty `QString` on the `sender()`?

```
void Main_Frame::process_toolbar_ac_evt(QObject &evt) {
    if (evt.objectName() ==  circle_id) {
        // If circle action has clicked, to this ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't the sender of your signal actually `toolbar`?

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Answer (score 1):

As you are connecting to one of `QToolBar`'s signals the `sender()` will be your tool bar object.

Simply use the `QAction` argument that is passed in the `QToolBar::actionTriggered` signal. That's what it is for.

NB: Avoid `QObject::sender()` wherever possible. It virtually breaks the desired decoupling achieved by signals and slots.